# Random walking on a board

Tags: mathematics, probability

[image]

There’s a pawn starting in the center of this game board. At each move, it can advance randomly towards any of the adjacent squares sharing a common side with equal chance. What’s the probability of landing on the crossed spot on the ninth move?

This question is from a Swiss math contest, the [FSJM](https://fsjm.ethz.ch/en/), in 2008.  The [original questions](https://fsjm.ethz.ch/static/oldwebsite/documents/22_demi_enonces_F.pdf) are only available in French

Comment: Can you please put your source in? It's actually required on this forum.

Comment: The source is in French though. https://fsjm.ethz.ch/static/oldwebsite/documents/22_demi_enonces_F.pdf

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in a different language. We just want to know where it comes from! Thanks

Comment: Your welcome Dr Xorile.

Comment: Edited to add links to the question itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $\frac{935}{13122}$

Proof

> After an even number of moves the pawn must be on one of the shaded squares
>  [image]
>  Due to the symmetry of the problem the probability of being on any of the four surrounding squares is equal so this simplifies the calculation a bit.
>  If the pawn is on the centre square at move $n$ then it has probability $\frac{1}{6}$ of being on each surrounding square at move $n+2$ and probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ of being back in the centre.
>  If the pawn is on a surrounding square at move $n$ it has probability of $\frac{1}{9}$ of being at the centre at move $n+2$. This means we generate the following probabilities after $2n$ moves:
>  **2 moves:** $p(centre) = \frac{1}{3}$, $p(surround) = \frac{1}{6}$ each
>  **4 moves:** $p(centre) = \frac{1}{9} + \frac{4}{54} = \frac{10}{54}$, $p(surround) = \frac{11}{54}$ each
>  **6 moves:** $p(centre) = \frac{10}{162} + \frac{44}{486} = \frac{74}{486}$, $p(surround) = \frac{103}{486}$ each
>  **8 moves:** $p(centre) = \frac{74}{1458} + \frac{412}{4374} = \frac{634}{4374}$, $p(surround) = \frac{935}{4374}$
>  which means it has probability of $\frac{935}{4374}$ for being in the top-left shaded square after 8 moves so $p=\frac{935}{13122}$ of being on the X after 9 moves

Comment: The value lines up with what I found running my script from working backwards, and overall this is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: The answer is correct!

Comment: @MichaelMoschella Thanks I'm glad your percentage lined up with my reasoning.

Comment: What? No Markov chain matrix multiplication?! A little part of me dies when Markov chains aren't used for problems like this. (+1 Nice answer!)

Comment: @DrXorile, arguably the iterative calculation on the even steps are using Markov chains with matrix $\binom{\frac{1}{3}\ \frac{2}{3}}{\frac{1}{9}\ \frac{8}{9}}$

Comment: @justhalf, that's true. But with the formalism you can work it out even by hand quite quickly. Because $M^8=((M^2)^2)^2$. So you can easily skip the step 6 bit.

Comment: @justhalf, please ignore the comment with the question I left before. I understood how you got the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

For simplification, I will represent squares with numbers 1-25 (With 1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 15, 18, 21, 23, and 25 unused) 2 is the goal square, and 13 is the starting point.

We can do this by working backwards, using the pretense that on each consecutive turn the pawn will end up on a "checkerboard" alternating from the previous turn:

Starting from 1 move to go,

> On square 7 there is a 1/3 chance to reach the goal, on all other squares there is a 0% chance

From 2 moves to go,

> On squares 2 and 6 there is a 100% chance to reach square 7, and on square 12 there is a 1/3 chance to reach square 7, (so effectively 1/9 total), on all else 0% chance

From 3 moves to go,

> On square 7, there is a 2/3 chance of landing on a 1/3 square, and a 1/3 chance of landing on a 1/9 square. This averages out to a chance of 7/27. On Square 17 there is a 1/3 chance to land on a 1/9 square, so there is a chance of 1/27, and on square 13 there is a 1/2 chance to land on a 1/9 square, so there is a chance of 1/18.

From 4 moves to go,

> On squares 2 and 6, you will always end on the 7/9 square. On squares 16 and 22, you will always end on  the 1/27 square, on square 12, you will have an equal chance to land on the 7/9, 1/18, and 1/27 squares, so this averages to 47/162, lastly on square 14 you have a 1/3 chance to land on a 1/18 square, giving you a 1/54 chance.

From 5 moves to go,

> On squares 9 and 19, there is a 1/3 chance to land on the 1/54 square, giving a 1/162 chance, on square 13 you take the average of squares 12 and 14 to get a 25/162 chance...

The more I'm doing this the more I'm realizing the ugly math here, and I'm realizing instead:

> I can run a script starting with all squares occupied with 0 except the goal square occupied by 1, and run a procedure to change each square to the average of each adjacent square, run this 9 times, and return the value in the start square. I will get back with a solution after running this

Update, using my script I got a solution of:

> 7.125438195397042%

Comment: The answer is correct! However, I highly suggest others to solve it without computers because this question was asked during a maths contest.

Answer (score 3):

> This can be solved with linear algebra as follows:
>
>  1. Create an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).
>  2. For each row in the matrix, scale all of the values so that the row sums to 1.
>  3. At this point, the value at row i, column j will be the probability that a single random step starting in cell i will land you in cell j.
>  4. Raise the matrix to the 9th power. If you're doing this by hand, you can do it in only 4 matrix multiplications if you're clever enough.
>  5. At this point, the value at row i, column j will be the probability that exactly 9 random steps starting in cell i will land you in cell j.
>  6. The row and column corresponding to the puzzle's specified starting and ending square will now contain the desired probability.
>
>  Here's a demonstration of this approach in Haskell (it requires [the `matrix` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.6.1)):
>
> ```
> import Data.Matrix
>
> adjacencies = [
>   [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]]
>
> normalize :: [Rational] -> [Rational]
> normalize xs = map (\x -> x / s) xs
>   where s = sum xs
>
> stepProbabilities = fromLists (map normalize adjacencies)
>
> walkProbabilities = stepProbabilities ^ 9
>
> -- Result: 935 % 13122
> main = print $ getElem 8 1 walkProbabilities
> ```

Answer (score 3):

One thing to know about FSJM problems is that they are to be solved with just pencil and paper, without a calculator.

I concur with hexomino in his answer and his method.  I used a different method to compute the result.  It is the "Markov chain matrix multiplication" method others mentioned.  I initially thought it would be much simpler or faster to compute, but it the end it is not significantly different.  I leave it here, it might be of interest to some.

> Like in hexomino's answer I consider the probability of being in the center versus being in one of the 4 surrounding "even" squares after 2, 4 and 8 moves.
>
>   When you start in the center and do 2 moves, you end up in the center 1 out of 3 times.  Or 3 in 9.
>   And when you start in a surrounding square and do 2 moves, you end up in the center only 1 out of 9 times.
>
>   You can write the transition matrix for 2 moves between these 2 positions.  The first row/column is the center, the 2nd row/column is any of the four surrounding squares.
>   $$\frac{1}{9}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 6 & 8 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
>   If you square this matrix 2 times, you get the transition matrix for 8 moves.
>   $$(\frac{1}{9}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 6 & 8 \\ \end{pmatrix})^2 = \frac{1}{81}\begin{pmatrix} 15 & 11 \\ 66 & 70 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
>   $$(\frac{1}{81}\begin{pmatrix} 15 & 11 \\ 66 & 70 \\ \end{pmatrix})^2 = \frac{1}{81^2}\begin{pmatrix} 225+726 & 165+770 \\ 990+4620 & 726+4900 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{6561}\begin{pmatrix} 951 & 935 \\ 5610 & 5626 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
>
>   (the matrix is complete here, but you actually need to compute only the bottom left term).
>
>   This matrix tells you that if you start from the center (1st column), the probability to end in a "corner" (bottom row) after 8 moves is
>   $$\frac{5610}{6561} = \frac{1870}{2187}$$
>
>   To end up on the big cross after one more move, you have to actually be in the top-left corner, which happens 1 out of 4 times, and then move up, which happens 1 out of 3 times.  Multiplying these probabilities you get the answer:
>
>   P(on X after 9 moves)
>   $$= \frac{1870}{2187} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{935}{13122}$$